# Python: Parse XML treating (hexadecimal) escapes as literal strings

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

I have XML which contains unusual (but escaped) characters:

```
<key code="51" output="&#x0008;"/> <!-- backspace -->
<key code="53" output="&#x001B;"/> <!-- escape -->
```

How can I parse this so that the values of the `output` attributes are the literal strings `"&#x0008;"` and `"&#x001B;"` (and not the actual backspace/escape control characters)?

Python parsers like `lxml.etree.fromstring` seem to always decode these—which is fine for common characters like `"&#x0097;" -> "a"`. Using `etree.XMLParser` with `resolve_entities=False` preserves things like `&amp;`, but not `&#x...;`, which I require.

---

I intend to parse a file containing lines like that shown above, manipulate the tree with python, and finally save it to another file which looks like the first.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you may have found a bug. Try asking on their mailing list first though. Someone there can probably either confirm whether it's a bug or if there's another flag you can set. http://lxml.de/index.html#bug-tracker